# How to set image in ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, src

I need to put my own image on some `imageView`. So that's why I created folder named "drawable" in res folder , and copy my Image in this folder , but now I don't know how to set this image to my `imageView` in XML code. Can anybody help? and sorry for English :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your layout XML file:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/your_image_name"/>
```

Replace `your_image_name` with the name of the image file without the extension (e.g. if your drawable file is called `img1.png`, the `src` attribute should have a value of `@drawable/img1`).

Comment: as I tried , I can't use images with type of .png , but with .jpg it works. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @HaykNahapetyan no you can use Jpg image also, you need to check the naming conversion for your image name.

Comment: oh I'm sorry , I did some other mistake , that's why I thought so :) , thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Set it using android:src=""

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_name" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/YourImageViewID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/Your_Image_Name"
   />
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

//set background as your image by calling the `android:background` attributes in your xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/myimage"
    />
```

**Note:** you no need to create any drawable folder by default android project will contain

```
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
```

you can put your image in that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
 android:layout_width="150dp"
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_height="150dp"
 android:id="@+id/image1"
 android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
 android:background="@drawable/image1"
          />
```